# scrape the about page of websites with Python

Tags: python

I am looking to scrape some content from some websites for research and I was hoping that using python and web scraping might speed up my process. I have used python and beautiful soup before for one small project to convert an xml from one format to another.

Comment: I don't see a question here. If you're just looking for a scraper, [scrapy](http://scrapy.org) is quite good.

Comment: I don't agree that the only way to go about solving a problem is to jump right in and start messing about. Particularly with coding because its so easy to get lost in technicalities. The flaw in that site you suggest, although I totally agree that learning through doing is incredibly important is that the research and theory is also important. There has to be a balance. I'm not asking you to provide me with a solution, just give me some pointers like the person answered below.  Interesting link though.

Comment: All true, but that does make your question unsuitable for Stack Overflow, see the [FAQ]. This site is best suited for practical problems, the kind you encounter after you have done your research and have chosen an approach.

Comment: Okay, thanks. Will bear that in mind in future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on how redundant is the structure of the data you want to extract, you could use several tools.

- If you're looking for extracting data always stored in the same DOM structure, [Scrapy](http://scrapy.org) could do the job.
- If the data is sparse and is stored in various places, maybe [BeautfulSoup4](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) or [lxml](http://lxml.de/index.html#documentation) could help you.
- If the data is generated by some JS code, have a look at [Selenium](https://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/py/index.html)

Here are a couple of resources you might find useful:

- PyCon 2012 Tutorial about web-scraping: http://pyvideo.org/video/609/web-scraping-reliably-and-efficiently-pull-data/
- http://isbullsh.it/2012/04/Web-crawling-with-scrapy/ (full disclosure, I wrote that)
- http://www.packtpub.com/article/web-scraping-with-python
- http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/