# How to use a python class with data objects in mysql

Tags: python, django

I am beginning to learn Python and Django. I want to know how if I have a simple class of "player" with some properties, like: name, points, inventory, how would I make the class also write the values to the database if they are changed. My thinking is that I create Django data models and then call the `.save` method within my classes. Is this correct?

Comment: Just a tip: your question is about ORM (Object-Relational Mapping) and can be solved in many ways, and Django models are one of them.

Comment: I think you should accept dm03514's answer on this one (they've spent time writing out what you could have discovered yourself, and quite easily). You're not going to get any answers other than read the tutorial and come back later if you have a specific problem...

Comment: I also refer you back to your previously closed question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11707709/scrape-the-about-page-of-websites-with-python

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct that you call the `save()` method to save models to your db, But you don't have to define the `save` method within your model classes if you don't want to.  It would be extremely helpful to go through the django tutorial which explains all.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/ 
Explains django models

django uses its own ORM (object-relational mapping)

This does exacxtly what it sounds like maps your django/python objects (models) to your backend.

It provides a sleek, intuitive, pythonic, very easy to use interface for creating models (tables in your rdbms) adding data and retrieving data.

First you would define your model

```
class Player(models.Model):
  points = models.IntegerField()
  name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

django provides commands for chanign this python object into a table.

`python manage.py syncdb`

you could also use `python manage.py sql <appname>` to show the actual sql that django is generating to turn this object into a table.

Once you have a storage for this object you can create new ones in the same manner you would create python objects

```
new_player = Player(points=100, name='me')
new_player.save()
```

Calling `save()` actually writes the object to your backend.

Comment: +1: nicely explained - hope you get this as an accepted answer

Answer (score 1):

You're spot on...

Start at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/

Make sure you have the python bindings for MySQL and work your way through it... Then if you have specific problems, ask again...